# Buil Error with AppleMach-Olinker Error iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

can anyone help me with this?

Ld "/Users/orkideh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_GUI-ffkeokshboqifhchxwfwfwbauahh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/New GUI.app/New GUI" normal i386
    cd "/Users/orkideh/Downloads/New GUI"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/orkideh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_GUI-ffkeokshboqifhchxwfwfwbauahh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/orkideh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_GUI-ffkeokshboqifhchxwfwfwbauahh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/orkideh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_GUI-ffkeokshboqifhchxwfwfwbauahh/Build/Intermediates/New GUI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/New GUI.build/Objects-normal/i386/New GUI.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreMedia -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework iAd -o "/Users/orkideh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_GUI-ffkeokshboqifhchxwfwfwbauahh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/New GUI.app/New GUI"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea what the error is and how I should fix this.any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i think  you are  missing some framework so please import these framework...

```
1. CoreGraphics
2. Social
3. Accounts etc.
```

And tell me which framework you have imported. ?

Comment: i checked all the frameworks that I'm using! first moved them all and then add them again but still same thing :(

Comment: Please close your xcode and open it.Because I've faced this problem.And i got solution using this way.After that my xcode work proper.